# Crack the password of a zip file given original files

Tags: zip, password-recovery, rarcrack

I have a legacy zip file encrypted with a password. I don't have its password - it has been lost. However, I have a few of the original unencrypted files - both txt and images. Is there a way to crack its password using these files?

Comment: If you [search](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58656/can-i-find-the-encryption-key-if-i-know-the-plain-text-and-the-encrypted-text-d) a [little bit](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/248321/is-it-possible-to-calculate-an-encryption-key-when-both-the-plain-text-and-ciphe) you might find the answer yourself, but I tend to say that with any recent encryption algorithm it is not any more feasible than a brute-force attack on the password itself.

Comment: Thank you. I did search a little bit before asking here. Guess I didn't use the right words.